# Re-rendering full calendar to display days as disabled

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using full calendar in combination with date picker, I am adding disabled class to days that are prior to the date in date picker. While everything works if I use the date on a different month in combination with:

```
.fullCalendar('gotoDate', date)
```

Selecting a date from the current month will not execute dayRender so disabled class will not be added in this view. This is, of course, due to calendar not re-rendering. I tried using rerended but that did not work.

Any way to get this done? See fiddle below plz.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fedorsmirnoff/80zb78ap/)

Comment: If its not possible to re-render, perhaps there is a way to loop through day in the current view and call dayRender on each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue with adding custom render function. Hope, it will help:)

```css
.disabled {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"/>
<div>
  <div id="fullcalendar"></div>
  <input type="text" id="startDate" />
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var startDate = new Date();

        $("#startDate").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
            //custom function for adding 'disabled' when month equals to current month
            if(startDate.getMonth() === e.date.getMonth()){
                $('.fc-day').each(function(){
                    var curDate = new Date($(this).data('date'));
                    $(this)[curDate < e.date ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
                });
                startDate = e.date;
            } else {
                startDate = e.date;
                $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('render');
                $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', e.date);
            }
        });

        $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },

            dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                if (date < startDate){
                    $(cell).addClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah I see what you did here :) I would much prefer to rerender using fullcalendar api but it seems there is no way to do that.

Comment: Yep. I also tried to do that via API. Seems, that it doesn't have ability to do that. Also there is no github questions for this case .